# How to ignore "-" and "." characters in a value during sort comparison?

Tags: javascript, sorting, sortcomparefunction, custom-compare

I have an html page that has a field that can be sorted. I also have created a javascript function that can sort that field in order. Let's imagine p_cSort is the 'id' name of that field.

```
function change_sort(neworder) {
 document.sortForm.p_cSort.value = neworder;
 document.sortForm.submit();
```

However when I have values like

```
12.34
12-35
12.36
12-33
```

and I search for them on my search page. The results returned are

```
12.34
12.36
12-33
12-35
```

How can I ignore the characters "." and "-" when sorting?

So the result I am looking for should be:

```
12-33
12.34
12-35
12.36
```

Comment: you'll have to temporarily remove those chars when sorting

Comment: Escape by what? Or do you mean "ignore in the sort"?

Comment: @Bergi Yes ignore in the sort

Comment: you should explain your definition of "sort", seeing as how "12.34" means something different than "12-35". My guess is the former is a single number and the latter is a range. Soo..how exactly should that be sorted? should "12.34" come before or after "12-33", seeing as how numerically "12.34", it would actually be a value within that "12-33" range...

Comment: @CrayonViolent I have edited to explain further the result I expected when I sort them. Hope it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make a custom sort function liek this:

```
var x = ['12.5', '11.3', '13-5', '10-0'];
x.sort(function(a, b){
    a = a.replace(/[-]/, '.');
    b = b.replace(/[-]/, '.');
    if( parseInt(a) < parseInt(b) ) return -1;
    if( parseInt(a) > parseInt(b) ) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Output:

```
["10-0", "11.3", "12.5", "13-5"]
```

This will also work if you have 125.5 and so on. because the `.` and the `-` are both used in the compare.

**Example with >= 100**

So input:

```
["100-0", "11.3", "12.5", "13-5"]
```

Will output

```
["11.3", "12.5", "13-5", "100-0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is using replace and sort function:

```
"12.34".replace(/[.-]/, '')
```

Full answer

```
var a = ["12.34", "12-35", "12.36", "12-33"];
var b = a.sort(function(a, b){
 return parseInt(a.replace(/[.-]/, '')) - parseInt(b.replace(/[.-]/, ''))
});
// now b contain sorted array
// ["12-33", "12.34", "12-35", "12.36"]
```

Comment: That would put `12.34` after `123.2`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Well, that's just what "ignoring those characters" would mean. Nothing wrong with the *answer* :-)

Comment: @Bergi You might be right - the solution might also be right - I simply pointed it out because it was hard to understand what OP meant, and it might not work as required. :-)