# jQuery on page load sorting will not sort with leading currency symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416096/sort-table-rows-by-class-on-page-load-jquery-javascript) I was trying to sort a table on page load without any client side table sorting toggle switches just so the table would be sorted for a user as they arrive on the page.

The question was answered and I got a pretty good response and thought i'd solved the issue so I went to sleep, so as I tried to use the code on my website today I realized the sorting technique is not working but works perfectly in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ghzch66e/12/.

So I then realized the table wont sort on my website because on the webpage the data contains a leading (£) symbol https://jsfiddle.net/ghzch66e/13/.

How can I make the table sort even with a leading (£) symbol.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
var dataRows = [];

//Create an array of all rows with its value (this assumes that the amount is always a number.  You should add error checking!!  Also assumes that all rows are data rows, and that there are no header rows.  Adjust selector appropriately.
$('#internalActivities > tbody > tr').each(function(i,j) {
   dataRows.push({'amount': parseFloat($(this).find('.amount').text()), 'row': $(this)});
})

//Sort the data smallest to largest
dataRows.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.amount - b.amount;
});

//Remove existing table rows.  This assumes that everything should be deleted, adjust selector if needed :).
$('#internalActivities').empty();

//Add rows back to table in the correct order.
dataRows.forEach(function(ele) {
   $('#internalActivities').append(ele.row);
})
});
```

Comment: Before you call parseFloat strip the currency symbol.

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360440/how-to-ignore-and-characters-in-a-value-during-sort-comparison maybe try to replace the symbol with null? just a guess.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121437/sorting-an-array-in-javascript-85-88-dollars-9-35-95-96-126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the "£" with "" when pushing it to the array

```
$('#internalActivities > tbody > tr').each(function(i,j) {
        dataRows.push({'amount': parseFloat($(this).find('.amount').text().replace(/£/,"")), 'row': $(this)});
      })
```

Comment: this works now I have a problem with the thead dissapearing on my website any ideas why?

Comment: can you show me in jsfiddle if you look here at this fiddle (which you can modify) https://jsfiddle.net/ghzch66e/14/ I am actually targeting the tbody but still the header is not there

Comment: ive fixed it lol i have the table sorter doubled up in my code thanks man

Comment: your welcome  happy to help - one thing -if you wanted the "£" - you could prepend it back in when displaying the row data after the data has been sorted. Happy Coding: